# Keyboard Extension : Weird label in Settings

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, info.plist, custom-keyboard

I've developed fully functional Armenian keyboard extension for iOS8 system.
When installing it on device or simulator, following "English" label is always displayed below the extensions name

[image]

In `Info.plist`following is specified

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>hy_AM</string>
<key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
<string>hy_AM</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Armenian</string>
```

Do I miss any setting ? 
How can I change "English" to let say "Armenian", or is it possible to get rid of it ?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Actually I find it now,

For changing that, right click on info.plist and select Open as source code. and then find PrimaryLanguage

This string value, en-US (English for the US) by default, expresses the primary language for your keyboard using the pattern -. You can find a list of strings corresponding to languages and regions at [This Link](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.14/CFLocaleIdentifier.c).

So I believe just changing it this way, would solve your problem :

```
<key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
<string>hy</string>
```

Just change it to your custom language and voila! :)

---

Be sure that the mentioned `PrimaryLanguage` property is a subproperty of

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
    <key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
    <string>hy_AM</string>`
```

Comment: I've tried the value `hy` as well, doesn't solve my problem. What link your pointing to ?

Comment: Oops! I missed the link! I edited answer and link is there now!

Comment: Yup, thanks for the try, but as I said thats not a solution for me, the issue still exists

Comment: Added some improvement in your answer and accepting it as answer ;)